# Difference between $J$ and $j$

Tags: calculus, integration

Let we write a Bassel equation, 
$$\Phi_k(r) = r^{1-\frac{d}{2}} \left(c_1 J_{1-\frac{d}{2}}(k r) + c_2 Y_{-1+\frac{d}{2}}(kr)\right).$$
In the case d=3, the solutions can be written as,
$$\Phi_k(r) = \hat{c}_1 j_0(k r) + \hat{c}_2 y_0(k r) = \hat{c}_1(k) \frac{\sin k r}{r} + \hat{c}_2(k) \frac{\cos k r}{r},$$
My question is why the $J$ is written as j in the 2nd line?

Source of this question: [Solution of a differentiation in integral form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437739/solution-of-a-differentiation-in-integral-form)

Answer (score 1):

They're Bessel function of different kinds, see [Bessel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Spherical_Bessel_functions%3a_jn.2C_yn)

Comment: can you check  question this please?

Comment: They have written that spherical solution for every k is $\phi_k$. What does it mean? Details in this question : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437739/solution-of-a-differentiation-in-integral-form

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean. If about $k$, because $k$ has some physical meaning, physicists like to explicitly point it out.