# Comparison between Bessel's coefficients

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, problem-solving

The spatial solution is written as 
$$\Phi_k(r) = r^{1-\frac{d}{2}} \left(c_1 J_{1-\frac{d}{2}}(k r) + c_2 Y_{-1+\frac{d}{2}}(kr)\right).$$
In the case $d=3$, the solutions can be written as
$$\Phi_k(r) = \hat{c}_1 j_0(k r) + \hat{c}_2 y_0(k r) = \hat{c}_1(k) \frac{\sin k r}{r} + \hat{c}_2(k) \frac{\cos k r}{r},$$
where $j_0$ and $y_0$ are the Spherical Bessel Functions.

My question is how $j_0$ and $y_0$ are co-related with $J_{1-\frac{d}{2}}$ and $J_{1+\frac{d}{2}}$. Canonical explanation with book reference will be helpful for me. 
Thanks in advance.

Reference post:[Solution of a differentiation in integral form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437739/solution-of-a-differentiation-in-integral-form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So let's look at what you have when $d=3$. When $d=3$,

$$\Phi_k(r)=r^{-\frac{1}{2}}\left(c_1J_{-\frac{1}{2}}(kr) + c_2Y_{\frac{1}{2}}(kr)\right).$$

In similar fashion to your previous post, we know that $J_{-\frac{1}{2}}(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi x}}\cos x $. You can prove this pretty easily using the exact same techniques as myself and the other user that answered. We also know that

$$Y_{\nu}(x) = \frac{J_{\nu}(x)\cos(\nu\pi)-J_{-\nu}(x)}{\sin(\nu\pi)}.$$

Letting $\nu = \frac{1}{2}$ we have that $Y_{\frac{1}{2}}(x) = -J_{-\frac{1}{2}}(x)$. So we see that in the case of $d=3$ that the only solution we need to concern ourselves with is $J_{-\frac{1}{2}}$.

Pursuing this, we have

$$\Phi_k(r) = Cr^{-\frac{1}{2}}J_{-\frac{1}{2}}(kr),$$

where $C = c_1-c_2$. This gives us that

$$\Phi_k(r) = Cr^{-\frac{1}{2}}\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi kr}}\cos(kr) = -C'(k)\frac{\cos(kr)}{kr} = C'(k)y_0(kr).$$

Here I've defined $C'(k) = -\frac{C}{\sqrt{k}}$.

In the general case, $j_n(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi x}}J_{n+\frac{1}{2}}(x)$ and $y_n(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi x}}Y_{n+\frac{1}{2}}(x).$ From this it's clear that your solution can be written in terms of these since your Bessel functions are evaluated at half integers. I have to get to a seminar so if you have questions, I will address them later.

Comment: Got it thanks. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Form Arfken's *Mathematical Methods for Physicist*:

> When the [Helmholtz equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_equation) is separated in spherical coordinates, the radial equation has the form
>   $$
> R'' + \frac{2}{r} R' + \left(k^2 - \frac{n(n+1)}{r^2}\right)R = 0. \tag{1}
> $$
>   If we substitute
>   $$
> R(k r) = \frac{Z(k r)}{(k r)^{1/2}}
> $$
>   equation (1) becomes
>   $$
> Z'' + \frac{1}{r} Z' + \left(k^2 - \frac{(n + \frac{1}{2})^2}{r^2}\right)Z = 0, \tag{2}
> $$
>   which *is* Bessel equation. $Z$ is a Bessel function of order $n + \frac{1}{2}$ ($n$ an integer). Because of the importance of spherical coordinates, this combination,
>   $$
> \frac{Z_{n+1/2}(k r)}{(k r)^{1/2}}
> $$
>   occurs quite often.
>
> Is convenient to label these functions as spherical Bessel functions with the following defining equations
>   \begin{align}
> j_n(x) &= \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2 x}} J_{n+1/2}(x), \\
> \\
> y_n(x) &= \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2 x}} Y_{n+1/2}(x).
> \end{align}

Any book on Bessel functions or Special functions will have detailed relations and properties. Specifically, being
$$
J_{n+1/2}(x) = \sum_{s=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^s}{s!(s+n+\frac{1}{2})!}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2s + n + 1/2}
$$
it's clear that
$$
j_0(x) = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2 x}} \sum_{s=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^s}{s!(s+\frac{1}{2})!}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2s + 1/2} = \frac{\sin x}{x},
$$
where we have used the [Legendre duplication formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendreDuplicationFormula.html)
$$
s!(s+\tfrac{1}{2})! = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2^{2 s + 1}}(2 s + 1)!.
$$

Analogously,
$$
y_0(x) = -\frac{\cos x}{x}.
$$

Comment: Thanks your addition makes me more comfortable to get.